# Problema con localStorage en Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, local-storage

Tengo un problema con google chrome tengo el siguiente código en una página:

```
function render() {
    localStorage.setItem('mail', $('#email').val());
    window.location.href = "https://ejemplo.com/registro";
}
```

y en la página a la que estoy redirigiendo con javascript tengo el siguiente código:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var mail = localStorage.getItem("mail");
        if(mail!=null) {
            $('#email').val(mail);
        }
    });
</script>
```

en Opera y Firefox me manda correctamente el valor que se almacena en el localStorage pero en Chrome no funciona siempre llega en null, ya intenté con sessionStorage y tampoco funciona. Alguien tiene alguna idea de cuál sea el problema?

Comment: Intentastes debuguear a ver ke sucede, en el inspector de objetos en la pestaña Aplicaion en LocalStorage que almacena si no pones el window.location.href = "...."

Comment: @DarielRamosDíazdeVillegas en efecto eso hice y si se almacena el valor en el localStorage si no le pongo el location.href pero al ponerselo por alguna razón se pierde el valor, cosa que en opera y firefox no sucede.

Comment: has lo siguente crea un link y ponle la misma url a la ke vas cuando haces location.href = "" y despues ke se ejecute la funcion render, has click en ese link y verifica si llega al otro lado localStorage

Comment: A ver si entendí, entonces de la función render quito el location.href y en otra pestaña pongo el link al que redirige. Despues hago que se ejecute la funcion render y posterior a eso cargo el link a ver si llega el localStorage?

Comment: Mas menos eso, la idea es ke verifiques si el location.href es el causantes del problema y no la navegacion hacia a pagina

Comment: pudieron resolver este problema me pasa lo mismo.. saludos